# Javascript change password by using an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new in Javascript and I want to make a code where a window will be open asking the user to type a specific password. If the password is correct then he "enters" the page. In the page, he can find an input and a button. He can change the password by filling the input and then pressing the Submit button. Basically to change the value of the variable. The problem is that I don't know how can I "pass" the input with id="changePass" to the variable pass1 and then I am not sure if the new password will be saved. Thank you in advance! Bellow you can find my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var entered = false;
var password;
var pass1="pass";
if (entered == false) {
password = prompt('Enter your password in order to view this page!', ' ');
if (password == pass1) {
alert('Correct Password, Enter the Club');
entered = true;
} else {
window.location = "";
}
} else if (entered == true) {
alert('You have already entered the password. Click OK to enter!');
}
</script>
    <input id="changePass"/>
    <button id="subimt" type"Submit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Never** perform security validation on the front end, if you are at all concerned about true security.

Comment: well I hope this is just a learning exercise since it is not very secure. But in order to save the password, you would need a place to save it to. Since you can not alter the document, you would need to use something like localstorage or a cookie. But in reality, passwords should be on the serverside where it is not visible to the user.

Comment: I am guessing this is some kind of homework right? So let's get it from the beginning. You have the pass1 variable set and you want if the user changes the input changePass and presses the subimt button to set the pass1 variable to the new value. Now what do you mean to be saved? If the user refreshes the page you want him to login with his new password? If yes you are looking for something like a local storage of browser since you don't seem to have a backend and Database?

Comment: First of all thank you about your answers. First of all, to be honest I didn't know that validations should not be performed on the front-end but it sounds logical. I will try to find information about local storage and cookie if this the only way. @Anastasios Selmanis first of all this is not a homework, and yes whenever the user presses the submit button the password will be saved and then if he refreshes the page he has to type the new password that he assignet to the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend you can't rely on browser storage and cookies for logging in users and keeping passwords. The least of your problems is that if a user clears his cookies and history you are going to lose it all. :)

This is why I asked if it is a homework or at least something that you don't really care to hold on to user credentials, and your users won't have any problem to re-enter the default password every once a while.

With that being said below is the code you want to store the password to [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
<input id="changePass"/>
<button id="changePassBtn" type"Button" onclick='changePassBtnClick()'>Change Password</button>


<input id="login"/>
<button id="loginBtn" type"Button" onclick='loginBtnClick()'>Login</button>


<script>
    if(!localStorage.getItem('password')){
      localStorage.setItem('password', 'pass');
    }

    function changePassBtnClick(){
      localStorage.setItem('password', document.getElementById('changePass').value);
      alert('Password changed');
    }

    function loginBtnClick(){
      if(document.getElementById('login').value == localStorage.getItem('password')){
        alert('Correct Login');
      }else{
        alert('Wrong Password');
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: First of all thank you about you answer this what I was thinking about, but according what you told me this is basically a bad decision, storing passwords on the front-end. At least I learned several thnigs with this question meaning the local storage and where I have to perform security validation!